# use SSL Client Certificate for further server side authentification

Tags: ssl-certificate, x509certificate

If Tomcat is set up for SSL mutual authentication you can get the client javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate from the servlet request.

In the server app I need a key to encrypt a file.

Is it a good idea to use a part of the Client X509Certificate, e.g. the SubjectPublicKeyInfo as encryption key?

The client Certificate should be as secret as any password, shouldn't it?

(this question has Java API example, but is not Java specific)

Comment: You have an encrypted connection to the client by which you can send data securely. Why do you need to add additional encryption with a key that the client already has?

Comment: The server should store some data in encrypted files. To encrypt, it needs a key. Obviously, the key should not be stored on the server. So it must come from the client. The client certificate goes to the server for each session. So the idea is to use it to encrypt the files. But I am not sure if this is secure.

Comment: Then, you want to encrypt a file so that the server can not decrypt it, but the client does. Supposing you have client certificates with RSA keys, the size of the message to encrypt is limited by the key size, so the server cant use the RSA public key directly. It needs to create a symmetric encryption key and send it to client in some way. For example encrypted with the RSA key or using DH agreement. Why does not the client send the encrypted file directly?

Comment: 3des only needs 128bits, so simply using an rsa public key should suffice (i.e. using a public key as des key)

Comment: _using a public key as des key_ Do you mean use directly the content of the public key as 3des key? Then anyone could decrypt the message. _public_ key means that the key can be distributed to anyone safely

Comment: Yes. I would generate the cert and it would never leave the client (except for being used as ssl client cert). Why should it be less secure than a password? (with the difference that a client cert goes over the wire within the ssl protocol)

Comment: A password is sent after the SSL channel is stablished, so it is allways kept secure between client and server. The public key of the certificate is exchanged during the SSL handshake phase, **before** stablishing the secure channel, so it is not encrypted Anyone sniffing the network could read the public key

Comment: Thanks, I did not think of this.

Comment: Too bad. Would have been an elegant way to bring a password to the server.

Comment: You would have an encrypted channel authenticated by both parties, which is the difficult part !. Once established you can transmit the passwords or encryption keys that you need